# How to programmatically add script or stylesheet on a per page basis in Docpad

Tags: docpad

How can I programmatically add script or stylesheet tag to a page specified in page's YAML front matter (meta)?

Assuming there is `src/documents/posts/a.html.eco` with following contents:

```
---
layout: default
scripts: ['a.js']
---

Blog post that requires a special javascript
```

and layout `src/layouts/default.html.eco` with following contents:

```
...
@getBlock('scripts').toHTML()
</body>
...
```

The final result for `posts/a.html` should be:

```
...
<!-- some extra stuff that was added when processing script tag -->
<script scr="/scripts/a.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

..while other pages shouldn't have a reference to `/scripts/a.js`

The comment above tag is just to show that there may be some processing envolved before injecting the tag.

I tried many approaches using different `events` in `docpad.coffee` file (including approach taken from `docpad-plugin-livereload` plugin) but every time I was facing the same problem - script tag was applied to all pages instead of being applied to `a.html` only. Here is one of my tries:

```
renderDocument: (opts) ->
  {extension,templateData,file,content} = opts
  if extension == 'html' and scripts = file.get('scripts')
    if typeof scripts != 'undefined'
      scripts.forEach (scriptName) ->
        @docpad.getBlock('scripts').add('<!-- custom script tag here -->')
```

I've also tried `render` event, `populateCollections` (which is not documented however I found it in `docpad-plugin-livereload` plugin) and even `extendTemplateData` events and no luck so far.

I know there is a method of doing this right inside a layout:

```
@getBlock('scripts').add(@document.scripts or [])
```

..which is totally fine and it really works as expected however it doesn't seem to provide enough freedom for me to manipulate the content before it's injected to a page.. And even if it's possible I won't like the idea of having some heavy logic inside layout template, I want it to be in a plugin/docpad.coffee

Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Have you tried the FrontEnd plugin? https://github.com/sergeche/docpad-plugin-frontend If that works for you say so, so I can put it in an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes, I've checked that plugin. It doesn't utilize Docpad's `@getBlock` to add scripts however, it creates custom @assets object, populates it and then iterates through it in the layout. I'm looking for solution that utilizes native Docpad's `@getBlock` helper.

Answer (score 0):

Try `templateData.getBlock('scripts').add` instead of `docpad.getBlock('scripts').add`

Comment: ,,while assigning any property to templateData and printing it on a page does work